# Is it possible to stop the marquee which has images as elements in it, after every images slides?

Tags: html, css

I have created one marquee with images as element.

Code is

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="30"  class="image-marquee" >
    <img src="images/cbr.png" alt="cbr-bike" name="CBR BIKE" style="float:left;" title="CBR BIKE" border="0" onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()" />
    <img src="images/blank.png" alt="aviator" name="blank"  style="float:left; cursor:default;"border="0" />
    <img src="images/aviator_.png" alt="cbr-bike" name="AVIATOR"  style="float:left;" title="AVIATOR" border="0" onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()"  />
    <img src="images/blank.png" alt="aviator" name="blank"  style="float:left; cursor:default;"border="0" />
    <img src="images/cbr.png" alt="cbr-bike" name="CBR BIKE" style="float:left;" title="CBR BIKE" border="0" onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()" />
    <img src="images/blank.png" alt="aviator" name="blank"  style="float:left; cursor:default;"border="0" />
    <img src="images/aviator_.png" alt="cbr-bike" name="AVIATOR"  style="float:left;" title="AVIATOR" border="0" onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()"  />
    <img src="images/blank.png" alt="aviator" name="blank"  style="float:left; cursor:default;"border="0" />
</marquee>
```

CSS

```
.image-marquee{ }
.image-marquee img{margin-top:70px;cursor:pointer; }
```

Is it possible to stop the marquee after every image slide and after some time it should run forward to next image?

Comment: Your code is messed up. Make sure to leave a blank line before and after the code and each line must have 4 spaces in front of it.

Comment: [No, really. Don't use it.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee)

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen this element in years. Please use transitions or animation nowadays: "*The marquee element is a presentational element that animates content. CSS transitions and animations are a more appropriate mechanism. [CSSANIMATIONS](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsCSSANIMATIONS) [CSSTRANSITIONS](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsCSSTRANSITIONS)*" from w3.org [11.3.2 The marquee element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> scrolldelay="2000"
>
> scrollamount="500"